# if __name__ == "__main__": SyntaxError but is written correctly

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I copied the part from another code where it works, however it's giving me this error and i don't know the reason:

The error is here if **name** == "**main**": but i already check the spaces and the _

```
 File "/Users/goncalo/Desktop/Python/GUI/Grafico/main.py", line 40
    if __name__ == "__main__":
                             ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code:

```
#importar as bibliotecas
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "Graficoteste.ui" #Innserir nome do arquivo

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #seccao para adicionar os botoes
        self.Botao1.clicked.connect(self.getCSV)
        self.Botao2.clicked.connect(self.plot)



     #seccao para adicionar funcoes
     def plot(self):
         x=self.df.loc[:][0]
         plt.plot(x)
         plt-show()


     #Esta función abre el archivo CSV
     def getCSV(self):
         filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
         if filePath != "":
             print ("Dirección",filePath) #Opcional imprimir la dirección del archivo
             self.df=pd.read_excel(str(filePath),header=None




if __name__ == "__main__":
   app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MyApp()
   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Check the line before the one which throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the brackets on the line before:
Change: `self.df=pd.read_excel(str(filePath),header=None`
To: `self.df=pd.read_excel(str(filePath),header=None)`

Often when you get a `SyntaxError` and the interpreter tells that the error is on for example line 40, the mistake is actually a missing comma, parentheses, or a quote on line 39.